# How to return only 1 field in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm trying to get the order number where a transactionId is equal to another variable I have in my code. My tolls.booths collection looks like this

[image: tolls.booths]

In my code, 
`def boothsException = booths.find([ "pings.loc.transactionId": tollEvent.id, "pings.loc.order":1] as BasicDBObject).iterator()
println boothsException`

I am getting `boothsException = DBCursor{collection=DBCollection{database=DB{name='tolls'}`
I would like to essentially say get where transactionId = 410527376 and give me that order number in boothsException (5233423).

Answer (score 2):

This is using [MongoDB Java Driver v3.12.2](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/).

The code extracts the value from the returned cursor. I am using newer APIs, so you will find some differences in class names.

```
int transId = 410527376;    // same as tollEvent.id

MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection
                                   .find(eq("pings.loc.transactionId", transId))
                                   .projection(fields(elemMatch("pings.loc.transactionId"), excludeId()))
                                   .iterator();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document doc = cursor.next();
    List<Document> pings = doc.get("pings", List.class);
    Integer order = pings.get(0).getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("loc","order"), Double.class).intValue();
    System.out.println(order.toString());    // prints 5233423
}
```

**NOTES:**

The query with projection gets the following one sub-document from the `pings` array:

```
"pings" : [
                {
                    "upvote" : 575,
                    "loc" : {
                            "type" : "2dsphere",
                            "coordinates" : [ .... ],
                            "transactionId" : 410527376,
                            "order" : 5233423
                    },
                    ...
            }
]
```

The remaining code with looping the cursor is to extract the `order` value from it.

The following are the *imports* used with the `find` method's filter and projection:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.*;
```